# Codename one. Changing a label's text dynamically using revalidate() is not working

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to change a label's text on the click of the button. So I change it using setText then I call revalidate() however when I run it and press the button, the text does not change in the label. here is my code. 
What am I doing wrong???

```
public void setUpSignUpDialog() {
    final Dialog signUpDialog = (Dialog) u.createContainer(theme, "SignUpDialog");
    signUpDialog.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(true);
    signUpDialog.setTransitionInAnimator(CommonTransitions.createDialogPulsate());
    signUpDialog.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createDialogPulsate());
    signUpDialog.showPacked(BorderLayout.CENTER, true);

    final TextField emailField;
    TextField passwordField;
    TextField repeatPasswordField;
    Button registerButton;
    final Label errorLabel;

    emailField = (TextField) u.findByName("EmailField", signUpDialog);
    passwordField = (TextField) u.findByName("passwordField", signUpDialog);
    repeatPasswordField = (TextField) u.findByName("RepeatPasswordField", signUpDialog);
    registerButton = (Button) u.findByName("SignUpButton", signUpDialog);
    errorLabel = (Label) u.findByName("ErrorLabel", signUpDialog);

    registerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (checkEmailField(emailField.getText())) {

            } else {
                errorLabel.setText("Please enter a valid email address");
                errorLabel.getStyle().setFgColor(ColorUtil.CYAN);
                signUpDialog.animate();
            }
            errorLabel.setText("Please enter a valid email address");
            errorLabel.getStyle().setFgColor(ColorUtil.CYAN);
            signUpDialog.revalidate();
        }
    });
}
```

Added the whole code of the signUpDialog. I added the code under the if statement just in case else wasn't being called. Still not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this code   signUpDialog.showPacked(BorderLayout.CENTER, true);
with signupDilaog.show(); and it will work

```
public void setUpSignUpDialog() {
    final Dialog signUpDialog = (Dialog) u.createContainer(theme, "SignUpDialog");
    signUpDialog.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(true);
    signUpDialog.setTransitionInAnimator(CommonTransitions.createDialogPulsate());
    signUpDialog.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createDialogPulsate());
  //  signUpDialog.showPacked(BorderLayout.CENTER, true);

    final TextField emailField;
    TextField passwordField;
    TextField repeatPasswordField;
    Button registerButton;
    final Label errorLabel;

    emailField = (TextField) u.findByName("EmailField", signUpDialog);
    passwordField = (TextField) u.findByName("passwordField", signUpDialog);
    repeatPasswordField = (TextField) u.findByName("RepeatPasswordField", signUpDialog);
    registerButton = (Button) u.findByName("SignUpButton", signUpDialog);
    errorLabel = (Label) u.findByName("ErrorLabel", signUpDialog);

    registerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (checkEmailField(emailField.getText())) {

            } else {
                errorLabel.setText("Please enter a valid email address");
                errorLabel.getStyle().setFgColor(ColorUtil.CYAN);
                signUpDialog.animate();
            }
            errorLabel.setText("Please enter a valid email address");
            errorLabel.getStyle().setFgColor(ColorUtil.CYAN);
            signUpDialog.revalidate();
        }
    });
signUpDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it should work
Is there any error message in output?
Can you post the whole codes of this signupDialog?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the else part of that statement is actually called by printing some text in the log.

Try:

```
errorLabel.getParent().revalidate();
//OR
errorLabel.getParent().repaint();
```

Comment: I added the code underneath the if statement still not working

Comment: try `forceRevalidate();`

Comment: I got it. I need to pust the signUpDialog.showPacked() at the bottom of the method.